# Make a unique select statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a select statement which, at least should, return only unique userId. If this does not happen and userIds are double a user did input something illegal.

To illustrate we use a simple `SELECT userId, name, FROM USER`. Now, usually you will make the userId unique/primarykey at the table level. Just for the sake of the example we don't.

The expected result would be:

```
userId    name
---------------
1         Roel
2         Joe
3         John
```

But the result is something like

```
userId    name
---------------
1         Roel
1         Roel
2         Joe
3         John
3         John
```

Is there possiblity to make the query in such a way that it would give an error when the result contains more than one the userIds?

Comment: how about adding `DISTINCT`? see my answer below.

Comment: DISTINCT does not solve the problem. It will make the result's userId's unique and thus ignoring the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    UserId, COUNT(*)
FROM 
    User
GROUP BY
    UserId
HAVING 
   COUNT(*) > 1
```

Any records returned from this will be those for which there is erroneous data.  That would be the simplest way to identify *when to raise* an error, but it wouldn't simply raise one for you.  You could wrap the above query into a procedure, and use some logic to determine whether to raise an error or run the main query.

Comment: This won't give an error only show the userIds that exist more than one time.

Comment: Yeah, I think though that if you wrap it in a procedure it would be a simple way to identify when to raise the error (see edit).

Answer (score 1):

Just add `DISTINCT`. And it will make your rows unique.

```
SELECT DISTINCT userId, name 
FROM USER
```

By definition, the `DISTINCT` keyword can be used to return only distinct (different) values.

**UPDATE 1**

The reason why is that you didn't specify a constraint on your table. Make a table definition like this.

```
CREATE TABLE userList
(
    ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT id_PK PRIMARY (ID),
    CONSTRAINT name_unique UNIQUE (NAME)
)
```

when you don't want `ID` to be auto_incremented, you can remove the `AUTO_INCREMENT` word on the table definition, or create a table definition like this

```
CREATE TABLE userList
(
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT id_PK PRIMARY (ID),
    CONSTRAINT name_unique UNIQUE (ID, NAME)
)
```

Comment: As you point out, distinct makes the rows unique. Infact they are not which is the problem. Therefor, I rather want an error.

Comment: @RoelVeldhuizen ok ok, now I understand your question. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @CommanderOnets as pointed out in my original question this query is only used as an example and I'm aware that making userId a primary would solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess this is importent during registration... so just count() the hits of a given username before you allow an INSERT.

Secondly make the name column UNIQUE and then you get the right error upon INSERT

Comment: The query `SELECT userId, name, FROM user` is used only as an example. The real world case is much more complex but comes down to this.

Comment: then Id go for a12jun solution with a small stored procedure raising an error (simply select the count column into that procedure)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is

```
SELECT *
FROM User
UNION
SELECT *
FROM User
```

The advantage of this is that you don't have to list the variables in SELECT. Usually, it is bad not to write explicitly the column names but I think this case is one of the rare cases where it makes sense.